# Using Generator functions to solve following recursive formulas

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, recursion

Assume we have:
\begin{cases}
a_{n} = 2^{n} \times \left(1 - b_{{\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor}}\right) \\
b_{n} = b_{n - 1} + \frac{a_{n}}{4^{n}} \\
b_{0} = 0
\end{cases}

I tried finding the closed formula for $a_{n}$ using generator functions. But I am stuck at this point:
$$ \frac{1}{1 - x} - A(\frac{x}{2}) = \frac{1}{1 - x} \cdot \left(A(\frac{x^{2}}{4}) - 1\right) $$

in which:
$$ A(x) = \sum_{i = 0}^{\infty} a_{i}x^{i},  B(x) = \sum_{i = 0}^{\infty} b_{i}x^{i}$$

This is how I got to this point:
$$ A(\frac{x}{2}) = (a_{0}, 1 - b_{0}, 1 - b_{1}, \dots) \Rightarrow \frac{1}{1 - x} - A(\frac{x}{2}) = (0, b_{0}, b_{1}, b_{1}, b_{2}, b_{2}, \dots) $$
$$ B(x^{2}) + xB(x^{2}) = \frac{1}{1 - x} - A(\frac{x}{2}) $$
and we also have:
$$ B(x) = \frac{A(\frac{x}{4}) - 1}{1 - x} $$
with a little algebra, you should get there.

Can the closed formula be found? If so how can I proceed with the solution? If you have any other solution I would be glad to hear it.

I'm not sure about the title of this question and which category of generator functions I should put this in. Please edit this if you know a better title.

P.S. 
$a_{n}$ counts the number of binary strings of length $n$ which doesn't have the same prefix and suffix of any length. (except the prefix or suffix that covers all the string.) Keep this in mind if it is helpful.

As mentioned in comments, you can find the sequence in [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A003000)

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151842/discussion-on-question-by-compuphysics-using-generator-functions-to-solve-follow); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.